# In Trello, is there a way to search through Activity and Checklist?

Tags: trello

It looks like Trello's default search goes only through cards' names and doesn't search through activities and checklists.

Is there a way to do that? Is it possible to use Google to search through all the information in the board?

If it can be done, than it would be possible to use manual tags by including **tttag-name_of_a_tag** anywhere. A search for *tttag* would give out all ofthe possible tags.

Comment: one way to search through details is to view all activities, but it's restricted only to recent ones

Answer (score 5):

Search will NOT search anything beyond the surface of the card itself. A very unfortunate limitation indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Trello doesn't search through checklists, but it will search through comments on the current board you are viewing.

Comment: At least for me, neither the search bar at the top of the page, nor the "search and filter cards"-button to the right search inside the comments.

Comment: Is there a feature request or requests for "better search"? I'd like to upvote and follow them.

Comment: i had the same experience where search did not search through comments. Bobby, how were you able to search through comments?

Comment: +1 Searching the card "back" doesn't work... most unfortunate. In fact that is so limiting that I would not have switched my company to Trello had I known that in advance.

Comment: Search through comments does *not* work yet.

Comment: @ripper234: Feature request for search in comments, you can vote here: https://trello.com/c/lX5WJW0o

Answer (score 0):

Id love to search ACTIVITY for a particular DATE - so i can retrospect my timesheets. but i have to keep clicking "load more activity" and go through a months worth of activity to get to the date i need. so slow.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/154883)