# Trello - Searchable List alternatives to Checklist?

Tags: trello

We have already established that Checklists are not searchable in Trello [from this question.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20244/in-trello-is-there-a-way-to-search-through-activity-and-checklist)

However, I would like to do a list of items similar to a checklist and have the ability to search the results.  For example, here is a card that I made to track the items I chose in a recent game bundle that I purchased:
[image: bundle card]

Is there an easy alternative way to create ordered lists that are searchable and can be easily edited?

Is using Markdown in the card description my next best option?  If so, it isn't as convenient.

Any steps necessary for converting checklists to this alternative list format would be appreciated, as there are already quite a few cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if you already have a checklist, you can drag over the text and copy the selection to the clipboard.

Your selected text will look like this:

```
Games
0%
✓
Vitrum
✓
Qasir Al-Wasat: A Night in-Between
✓
Zombies. - Groupees Limited Edition
✓
Orczz

Music
0%
✓
Lane 8 - Special Collection
✓
Play it Forward
```

To make life easier, I pasted the text into the nearest available text editor (which was [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)).  In this editor, the checkmark (✓) was converted to a question mark (?).  In the find and replace menu, I enabled the extended search mode and replaced "?" with "\n + ", and also replaced "0%" with "/n/n".

This changed the text to passable [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), allowing Trello to display the checklists as searchable lists in the description field of the card.
[image: Checklist converted to list]

I have about 50 cards on this board, and it didn't take too long to convert everything over.  Having all of the the cards searchable was worth the extra effort.

Hopefully, this workaround will eventually be obsolete, but in the meantime, feel free to use these steps to obtain searchable lists.